# Trying to subtract DateTime "System.FormatException: String '12/9/2019 12:00:00 AM' was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Tags: c#, datetime, subtraction, timespan, formatexception

So I'm trying to make a check for an `Order`. The difference between `ArriveTime` and `OrderDate` should be between 10 minutes and 2 hours. I formatted everything to what I think was correct, but I still get the error.

The values I put in `ArriveTime` is `DateTime.Today` and in `OrderDate` I put in `DateTime.Now`.

Code:

```
private bool TimerRequirements(IOrderData orderData)
{
     DateTime arriveTime = DateTime.ParseExact(orderData.ArriveTime.ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss:tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
     DateTime orderDate = DateTime.ParseExact(orderData.OrderDate.ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss:tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


     if (orderData.ArriveTime != null && Convert.ToDateTime(arriveTime.Subtract(orderDate)) >= orderData.OrderDate.AddMinutes(10) ||
            orderData.ArriveTime != null && Convert.ToDateTime(arriveTime.Subtract(orderDate)) <= orderData.OrderDate.AddHours(2))
     {
         return true;
     }
     else
     {
         return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: Dates have no format, they are binary values. The code *causes* the error by trying to convert the dates ti strings then back to dates. Just use `orderData.ArriveTime - orderData.OrderDate` to get the difference as a Timespan

Comment: But than I get "Operator <= cannot be applied to operands of type TimeSpan? and DateTime"

Comment: Yes, because the rest of the code is wrong too. The difference between two days is a duration, eg 1 hour or 1 minute, not a date

Comment: How do I say hours in C#? Just 1, 2 and 3?

Comment: [`TimeSpan.FromHours(1)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.fromhours)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dates have no format, they are binary values. The code causes the error by trying to convert the dates ti strings then back to dates. Just use

```
TimeSpan diff=orderData.ArriveTime - orderData.OrderDate;
```

to get the difference as a [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.8), for example :

```
var diff=orderData.ArriveTime - orderData.OrderDate;
var inRange= (diff>=TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10) && diff<TimeSpan.FromHours(2));
return inRange;
```

The difference between two dates is a duration, not a date. In .NET that duration is represented by the [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.8) class. You can generate TimeSpan values using its constructor, or through methods like [FromHours](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.fromhours?view=netframework-4.8) and [FromMinutes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.fromminutes?view=netframework-4.8)

If `OrderDate` and `ArriveTime` are `DateTime?`, you'll get a `TimeSpan?` instead of `TimeSpan`. If any of those values is null, the difference will also be null.

In this example :

```
class Order{
    public DateTime? OrderDate{get;set;}
    public DateTime? ArriveTime{get;set;}
}

var orderData=new Order{};
TimeSpan? diff=orderData.ArriveTime - orderData.OrderDate;
```

`diff` is `null`. Both comparisons will return `false` so `inRange` will be `false`